# Error: Device or resourse is busy

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling

I'm trying to write a simple module, which should replace irq 1 handler. And all the time I get following error:'-1 Device or resourse busy'. Is it any way to fix it?
Here's my code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/workqueue.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <asm/io.h>


irqreturn_t myhandler(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs) 
{
  printk(KERN_ALERT"\n\nMy interrupt handler\n\n");
  return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

int init_module()
{
  int res;
  free_irq(1, NULL);                  
  res = request_irq(1, (void*)myhandler,0, "my_handler", (void*)(myhandler)); 
  return res;
}

void cleanup_module()
{
  free_irq(1, NULL);
}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Maybe anybody can say what's wrong.
PS. I'm working with 2.6.39.3 kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of system (architecture) are you on?

On a normal PC, IRQ 1 is the 8042 (keyboard controller) and already has an interrupt handler.  You are passing 0 into `request_irq()` for `flags`, so you're asking to register a handler for a non-shared interrupt.  The core kernel interrupt code will look and see that there is already another handler registered for that IRQ, and return `-EBUSY` from `request_irq`.

You can't override the existing handler by registering another handler for the same IRQ.  You need to unregister the first one before you can register a new one.

You can look at /proc/interrupts to see what is already using IRQ 1 on your system.

Comment: Ok, but what about 'free_irq(1, NULL);'? It should unregister default handler. But I've just found out that the problem (I'm 90% sure) is in free_irq (tried to use free_irq 10000 times on the same irq, and no mistakes were found).

Comment: The second parameter of `free_irq` is the device ID, and if that pointer doesn't match the existing handler's value, `free_irq` will fail.  Assuming you're on a PC, `drivers/input/serio/i8042.c` is what does `request_irq` and it never passes in a NULL device ID.  So you're not actually freeing the existing handler.

Comment: I dont really understand why it happens. I mean that in all manuals I read second parameter of free_irq is always NUll. And if free_irq second parameter cant be NULL, then how to get id to remove default handler?

Comment: Not sure what "manual" you are reading, but if you look at the actual kernel source, you can see that the second parameter of free_irq is almost never NULL.  You need to pass in the same value as the original request_irq().  Probably the simplest thing to do is to just register the first IRQ -- ie on a PC don't load the i8042 driver.